# Helicon Zoo/ISS 400 Bad Request error when accessing long url

Tags: iis, ruby-on-rails-4, iis-7.5, dragonfly-gem, heliconzoo

I am using the Dragonfly gem in a Ruby-on-Rails app to generate converted image URL's on the fly but when I try to access the  image's url I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.
```

This seems to be coming from IIS and only occurs when the url is bigger than 256 Bytes. How would one go about increasing the maximum url size for a Helicon Zoo project within ISS. I have already tried the solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded) with no success.

**Edit:**
This is the link (with the domain redacted):

> http://{domain}.com/media/W1siZiIsIjIwMTQvMDgvMTkvNmVqb3JuMmd4aF9BSVRfT0ZGSUNFX1RSQVNQQVJFTlRfRURHRS5wbmciXSxbInAiLCJjb252ZXJ0IiwiLWZ1enogMjUlIC1maWxsIFwiI2NjY2NjY1wiIC1vcGFxdWUgd2hpdGUiXSxbInAiLCJyb3RhdGUiLCI1MC41MDY1MDU2NjI3NzkzMiJdLFsicCIsImNvbnZlcnQiLCItZnV6eiAxJSAtdHJhbnNwYXJlbnQgd2hpdGUiXV0?sha=3062766b

Which was generated by this code:

```
area_url = Area.find(params[:id]).image.convert('-fuzz 25% -fill "#cccccc" -opaque white')
area_url = area_url.rotate(params[:theta]).convert('-fuzz 1% -transparent white').url
```

Comment: Hello. Could you please to show your URL?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem by returning the image directly from this controller rather than returning the Dragonfly URL.

```
area_overlay = Area.find(params[:id]).image.convert('-fuzz 25% -fill "#cccccc" -opaque white')
area_overlay = area_overlay.rotate(params[:theta]).convert('-fuzz 1% -transparent white').file

send_file area_overlay, :type => 'image/png', :disposition => 'inline'
```